# Swift Tab Bar Badge

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, badge

I have 2 `UIViewController`

1- `UIViewController` with `UICollectionView`. In cell I have `UIButton` and `UILabel`. When I press `UIButton` I have save text from `UILabel` to UserDefaults array. (Main screen)

2- `UIViewController`

When I launch the app I want to tap the `UIButton` in cell and show the badge with array.count (for example I tap on 3 different Button and array have 3 count) on second Tab Bar Item

Im tried to do this through the protocol in `UICollectionViewCell` class and add the extension to `UIViewController` with CollectionView

Answer (score 0):

In collection ViewController at  `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` or at any part of code that you need to change `secondViewcontroller` Tabbar badge

Just do this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

 if let tabItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items
        {
            // In this case we want to modify the badge number of the seond tab:
            let tabItem = tabItems[1]
            tabItem.badgeValue = "1" // set count you need
        }
}
```

Comment: you have tabbar with two viewcontrollers ?? , share your code i test above code and works very nice